# JavaFX-SceneBuilder - Can't access fx:id when opening new window

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have this code (part of a quite big application):
The following function is located in the controller class of the project.

```
public void callSearch(){
    Stage supplyStage = new Stage();
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("supplyResult.fxml"));

        supplyStage.setTitle("Supply Result Set");
        supplyStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1400, 900));
        supplyStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        typeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Supply, String>("type"));
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Supply, String>("name"));
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Supply, String>("order_date"));

        pricePerUnitColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pricePerUnit"));
        quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
    }
    catch (NullPointerException npe){
        System.out.println("Null...");
    }

    searchSupplyStartDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDateDatePicker.getValue());
    searchSupplyEndDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(endDateDatePicker.getValue());

    tableOutput.setItems(myMain.getSupplies(searchSupplyStartDate,searchSupplyEndDate,null,null));
}
```

My problem is that I get a `NullPointerException` in the line `typeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Supply, String>("type"));`

In previous version of the application I had the columns in the same window as the rest of the scene. Now I try to add a second window when displaying the same stuff, to make the first scene a bit more beautiful. (the code was working when I had one scene).

In fact, to make things clear, i want with the press of a button, the function callSearch() to be called. Then a window appears, with a table of 5 columns attached: typeColumn, nameColumn, dateColumn, pricePerUnitColumn, quantityColumn. Those 5 columns are declared in the (only) controller of the project, so i thought that they are visible in any fxml file in the project, but that's not the case.

Does anybody know what am I missing? the `typeColumn` is visible from the `SupplyResult.fxml` in scene builder, but does not seem to execute the code it has to...

Comment: If `typeColumn` is defined in `supplyResult.fxml`, meaning that in `supplyResult.fxml` has an element `<TableColumn fx:id="typeColumn" .../>`, then `supplyResult` will be initialized in the controller for that FXML file, not in the current object (the object on which `callSearch()` is being invoked, whatever that object is). If not, it's not really clear what you're setup is. Can you write a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @James_D you are right! typeColumn and all the columns are defined in supplyResult.fxml. I understand what you are saying, but i don't know what the solution to that is. Maybe i should make a seperate controller for each fxml file?

Comment: Yes, each FXML file should have its own controller class.